# How to get specified roots from xml?

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I have XML file like below

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Movies>
    <servername>
           raaja
    </servername>
    <moviename>
           xyz
    </moviename>
    <city>
           Hyd
    </city>
    <theatername>
           abc
    </theatername>
    <noofreels>
           16
     </noofreels>
     <aspectratio>
         216
     </aspectratio>
</Movies>
```

I want the values of tags servername and theatername. Rest I dont want. How to get these using java. Is it possible to get the value using tagnames.

Comment: The short answer is that you can't since the input you show is NOT valid XML and cannot be parsed as XML by an XML parser (in any language).  It is not valid because it has multiple root elements.  You will need to split this up into multiple files before parsing it as XML.

Comment: Please post the **exact** expected result (as code).

Answer (score 1):

One way to accomplish this is to use the DOM parser included with the JDK.  For example:

```
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import java.io.StringReader;

...

// Creates a new DOM parser instance.
DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

// Parses XML and creates a DOM document object.
// The XML variable is your XML document above stored as a string, but you could
// easily read the contents from a file or database too.
Document document = documentBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(XML)));

// Get the text content of <theatername> using the DOM API and print it to stdout.
String theaterName = document.getElementsByTagName("theatername").item(0).getTextContent().trim();
System.out.println(theaterName);
```

Using StAX:

```
XMLInputFactory xmlInputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
XMLStreamReader xmlStreamReader = xmlInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(new StringReader(XML));
String theaterName = null;
while (xmlStreamReader.hasNext()) {
    if (xmlStreamReader.next() == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT) {
        if ("theatername".equals(xmlStreamReader.getLocalName())) {
            theaterName = xmlStreamReader.getElementText().trim();
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(theaterName);
```

Comment: How do we implement with stax?